# Drupal 7 page layout suggestions-separate layout for each page

Tags: theming, hooks

I need to create some layout for each pages.Suppose i have a page called "our dishes" and i need a different page layout for it.I need different layouts for all the pages like Guest book,Photo gallery careers etc.

How can i achieve this.I have a content type called 'ourdishes'.I heard that page--content_type_name.tpl.php is useful for this.So i created page--ourdishes.tpl.php page in theme folder.
i cleared the cache .But i don't know how to get the layout to the specific page.I have a menu item called 'our dishes' and when i click on that menu the default page.tpl.php layout is loading....

could you please provide the exact method for this?

So how can i inform the Drupal system about this new page .How will Drupal identify this theme for the page 'our dishes' ? How can i suggest it in template.php file?

Also if i have no such content type and i using the basic page for 'our dishes',how can i implement it?

thanks in advance,

Hari.

Comment: this can help a lot http://drupal.org/node/1089656 read comments with examples, btw

Comment: You making this difficult for yourself, just use Display Suite, does exactly what you require.